# Where is tMatchGroup located in Talend Open Studio for Big Data

Tags: bigdata, talend, data-quality

I'm learning Data Quality with Talend Open Studio for Big Data version TOS_DQ-20141207_1530-V5.6.1.zip.

According to my problem, I want to use tMatchGroup but I realize that it doesn't appear in the Palette of Talend Studio. In the help.talend.com, they said that I have to subscribe to one of "Talend Platform products". (https://help.talend.com/display/TalendsComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tMatchGroup)

Could anyone tell me how I can find this platform? I did some research but I don't know exactly where it is.

Thank you very much. 
p/s: Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the tMatchGroup component is only available in Talend Platform for Data Services (the paid version of Talend). So since you're using the Open Studio, you won't be able to access it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I had tried to download the commercial version and use as a trial, I didn't find that?

Comment: The trial version is not the same as the Platform version. It gives you most of the features but not all.